# React Native TextInput on iPhone initially show all the content inside

Tags: javascript, css, ios, react-native

I have a TextInput component with limited width, while the content inside sometimes longer. I set `numberOfLines` to 1 and expected that each time the content's length larger than the input's width, the overflow part will be hidden. It goes fine on Android, but in iOS, initially it's still show all the content, the overflow part is placed in a new line, but when the input is focused, it becomes as normal as I expected. How can I fix this.

At the first time, when value is set by `useEffect`
[image: At the first time, when value is set by useEffect]

When the input is focused
[image: When the input is focused]

Code:

```
<TextInput
    allowFontScaling={false}
    autoComplete="off"
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    onChangeText={e => {
        onChange(e);
        trigger && trigger([triggerTags]);
    }}
    value={value}
    autoCorrect={false}
    spellCheck={false}
    placeholderTextColor={Colors.placeholder}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    style={[
        {
            zIndex: 100,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 12,
            width: Sizes.width(76),
            height: 40,
            marginTop: 8,
            color: Colors.text,
            fontSize: Sizes.h6,
            paddingHorizontal: Sizes.padding,
            backgroundColor: !editable ? '#E5E5E5' : undefined,
            textAlign: 'center',
            paddingVertical: 0,
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
         },
         inputStyle,
      ]}
      // multiline={false}
      numberOfLines={1}
      maxLength={maxLength}
      keyboardType={keyboardType}
      editable={editable}
/>
```

Comment: any expo snack for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, just change `textAlign` from `'center'` to `undefined`